# Decorator pattern with Ninject

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, service-layer

I am trying to apply [this](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) approach to make a validation wrapper. I have created the following Interfaces and I am using Ninject as my DI Container

```
public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand>
    {
        void Handle(TCommand command);
    }

public interface IValidator<T>
{
    IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(T command);
}

public class ValidationCommandHandlerDecorator<T>:ICommandHandler<T>
{
    private readonly ICommandHandler<T> _decoratee;
    private readonly IValidator<T> _validator;

    public ValidationCommandHandlerDecorator(ICommandHandler<T> decoratee,IValidator<T> validator )
    {
        _decoratee = decoratee;
        _validator = validator;
    }
    public void Handle(T command)
    {
        this._validator.Validate(command);
        this._decoratee.Handle(command);
    }
}

public class SaveNewOsiRequestController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ICommandHandler<OsiRequest> _osiRequestSaveHandler;

    public SaveNewOsiRequestController(ICommandHandler<OsiRequest> osiRequestSaveHandler)
    {
        _osiRequestSaveHandler = osiRequestSaveHandler;
    }
}
```

And the following is how I am injecting the concrete classes into the controller:

```
        kernel.Bind(typeof (IValidator<>)).To(typeof (OsiRequestValidator));

        kernel.Bind(typeof (ICommandHandler<>))
            .To(typeof (SaveOsiRequestCommandHandler))
            .WhenInjectedInto(typeof (ValidationCommandHandlerDecorator<>));

        kernel.Bind(typeof (ICommandHandler<>))
            .To(typeof (ValidationCommandHandlerDecorator<>))
            .WhenInjectedInto(typeof(SaveNewOsiRequestController));
```

the code is working fine without any problem. However the question is how can I do the same injection for another controller with Ninject? To make it simple I want to inject Another `Validator` and Another `CommandHandler` to Another `Controller` like this:

```
        kernel.Bind(typeof (IValidator<>)).To(typeof (ANOTHER_Validator));

        kernel.Bind(typeof (ICommandHandler<>))
            .To(typeof (ANOTHER_CommandHandler))
            .WhenInjectedInto(typeof (ValidationCommandHandlerDecorator<>));

        kernel.Bind(typeof (ICommandHandler<>))
            .To(typeof (ValidationCommandHandlerDecorator<>))
            .WhenInjectedInto(typeof(ANOTHER_RequestController));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you're doing generic binding, but you are using it in specific situations.  You only want to use generic binding when you want it to apply to all situations of that binding (or at least all the situations you can conditionally bind to).

For this, you can just as easily do this:

```
kernel.Bind<IValidator<OsiRequest>>().To<OsiRequestValidator>();

kernel.Bind<ICommandHandler<OsiRequest>()
        .To<SaveOsiRequestCommandHandler>()
        .WhenInjectedInto<ValidationCommandHandlerDecorator<OsiRequest>>();

kernel.Bind<ICommandHandler<OsiRequest>()
        .To<ValidationCommandHandlerDecorator<OsiRequest>()
        .WhenInjectedInto<SaveNewOsiRequestController>();
```

Then each additional would be:

```
kernel.Bind<IValidator<DifferentRequest>>().To<DifferentValidator>();

kernel.Bind<ICommandHandler<DifferentRequest>()
        .To<DifferentRequestCommandHandler>()
        .WhenInjectedInto<ValidationCommandHandlerDecorator<DifferentRequest>>();

kernel.Bind<ICommandHandler<DifferentRequest>()
        .To<ValidationCommandHandlerDecorator<DifferentRequest>()
        .WhenInjectedInto<DifferentRequestController>();
```

You could change the last binding so you wouldn't have to declare it for each type:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof (ICommandHandler<>))
        .To(typeof (ValidationCommandHandlerDecorator<>))
        .WhenInjectedInto<ApiController>();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Erik. It was a life saver. Just a question. Am I following right approach? Is injecting Specific concrete classes to a generic interface, Correct at all from the architectural standpoint?

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh - Well, when you need specific instances in specific situations, you don't have much choice. You could simplify this if you could figure out a way to call a generic implementation with just the types from the interface, but your implementations don't seem to do that.  Also, you could reusing the last binding, since that's generic.. see my update.  This takes advantage of the fact that Ninject will walk look at base classes when using `.WhenInjectedInto()`

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh - but the other two would have to remain specific because there's no way to map a generic type to a specific type automatically.